# Let $G = D_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Prove that $G \space / \space Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Problem: Let $G = D_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$. Prove that $G \space / \space Z(G)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Here $Z(G)$ is the center of G, which I have figured out is of order 6. So, $|G \space / \space Z(G)|=24\space/\space6=4$ so whatever it is isomorphic to must have order 4. Now since G is not abelian then $G \space / \space Z(G)$ is not cyclic and cannot be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$ (is this true? I think it is). So, I can see it must instead be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

But how do I prove this rigorously? Or, is there an isomorphism that takes
$G \space / \space Z(G)$ to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ that is easy to find? I haven't been able to come up with one yet.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: $Z(H\times K)= Z(H)\times Z(K)$, and if $N\triangleleft H$ and $M\triangleleft K$, then $(H\times K)/(N\times M)\cong (H/N)\times (K/M)$.

Comment: And, yes; if $G/N$ is cyclic, where $N\leq Z(G)$, then $G$ is abelian. So $G/Z(G)$ cannot be $C_4$ and so must be the Klein $4$-group.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks! So if I understand correctly, $Z(D_4) = N and Z(\mathbb{Z}_3) = M)$ so the factor is isomorphic to $D_4/Z(D_4) \times \mathbb{Z}_3/Z(\mathbb{Z}_3)$? Then I can see that $D_4/Z(D_4)$ itself is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but what happens to the $\mathbb{Z}_3/Z(\mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Comment: What is the center of an abelian group? And what happens when you quotient out a group by itself?